# How can I initiate a controller using javascript (no directive)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use the $location service when an jQuery ajax event is successful.

I can't seem to find a way to use the service other then using it in the controller, and i only use the controller only when the ajax query success is done.

I am not sure how to do this,I have been trying to figure this out for hours and can't find a solution.

Here is my code

```
 $.post('#',selectedOrderMethod).done(function(){

      //Won't work because my ng-controller directive is looking a controller that doesn't exist      

    myApp.controller("myCtrl",function($scope,$location){
        $location.path('/basemenu');
        });

   });
```

Comment: Why is this an issue I guess?  Wait, you have the controller in the callback???

Comment: Are you unable to use angular's Resource or generic http functions inside a controller, and then use `$location` in callback?

Comment: This is untested, but you could trying something along the lines of `angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$location');`

[Services outside of scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312948/service-functions-outside-angularjs-scope)